# sending random messages with smtplib python

Tags: python, random, smtp

I want to send random messages using smtplib in python, I wrote this code:

```
import random, string, smtplib


def generator():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))

def login():
    try:
        global email, server
        email = ''
        pswd = ''
        smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        port = 587
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
        server.ehlo()
        if smtp_server == "smtp.gmail.com":
            server.starttls()
        server.login(email,pswd)

    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print('error')

def send():
    try:
        recipient = ''
        message = generator()
        count = 10
        lol = 0
        while lol < count:
            lol+=1
            server.sendmail(email,recipient,message)
            print('done')

    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print('error')

login()
send()
```

I've received the messages but with the same string, I also tried to make a list of random strings and then make the message variable chose randomly from there using `random.choice()` but it didn't work either.

What could the problem be?

Comment: I would be careful sending a lot of emails containing random strings (even if it's just to yourself), you run the risk of getting your email blacklisted as spam

Comment: reason why you are getting the same string is because you are generating the message first and then going into the loop. This is a mistake, go into the loop first, then do `message = generator()` inside the while loop. Done

Comment: @Iain Shelvington thanks but I'm just using this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake: generating one message with `message=generator()` and using that same `message` inside the loop. This is why it is always the same string.

You should call `generate()` every time you iterate through the while loop like this:

```py
count = 10
lol = 0
while lol < count:
    lol+=1
    server.sendmail(email, recipient, generator())
    print('done')
```